# Read binary file (docx, jpg) line by line java

Tags: java, file-io

Here is my code:

I get the `file` with a file chooser

```
BufferedReader br = null;
BufferedReader reader;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    lines = 0;
    while (reader.readLine() != null) lines++;
    reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String[] wholeFile = new String[lines];
    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        int counter = 0;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String decode = Decode(sCurrentLine);
            System.out.println(decode);
            wholeFile[counter] = decode;
            counter++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I save the file line by line it can't be opened properly (Word says it's damaged).
Should I use other character encoding?

Comment: Use a byte oriented stream to read/write it.

Comment: Don't read binary formats as characters nor line-by-line. Use InputStream/OutputStream to read as bytes. And what is your `Decode` function doing? That's probably damaging the file as well.

Comment: The whole example leaves out the exact problem statement: What do you want, and what do you get instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read `docx` and `jpg` files using `readLine()`. You need to use a byte-oriented stream.

You may use this code:

```
File f = new File("path-to-your-file");
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f)); //to read the file
byte[] b = new byte[(int)f.length()]; //to store the bytes
int l = dis.read(b); //stores the bytes in b
dis.close();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("new-file"))); // to write the file
dos.write(b,0,l); //writes the bytes from b to the file
dos.close();
```

Comment: what does the variable `l`?

Comment: @MaxiKopp It just counts the number of bytes read. Its value is the same as `f.length()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `readLine()`. That means the input is separated at each newline and those bytes get lost in the process.

Since you are reading binary data, you shouldn't read it line by line. Why do you do that in the first place?